# Slightly non-horizontal arrow in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

I have written the following diagram with tikz-cd:
[image]

As you can see, the middle "maps to" arrow is very slightly non horizontal, but I don't know why.
Maybe the technique I used to set arrows between arrows is not the best way to do the job, but after a short search here, I came to the conclusion that nobody has any better idea.

my code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
G \arrow[d, "f"', ""{name=f}] \arrow[r, maps to] & Z(G) \arrow[""{name=zf}, d, "f\mid_{Z(G)}"] \\
H \arrow[r, maps to]                 & Z(H)
\arrow[maps to, from=f, to=zf, shorten <= 5pt, shorten >= 5pt]
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Show a complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two vertical arrows have slightly different length. You can fix it by smashing the parentheses, which are the cause for this.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
G \arrow[d, "f"', ""{name=f}] \arrow[r, maps to] &
  \smash{Z(G)}\vphantom{G} \arrow[""{name=zf}, d, "f|_{Z(G)}"] \\
H \arrow[r, maps to] & \smash{Z(H)}\vphantom{H}
\arrow[maps to, from=f, to=zf, shorten <= 5pt, shorten >= 5pt]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `G\mathstrut` and `H\mathstrut` in the left column, `Z(G)` and `Z(H)` in the right column.

Note that `\mid` is the wrong symbol for the restriction; use just `|`.